# Expanding environment variables with sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to write a sed command to replace tokens in a file with values from environment variables like so:

```
export my_var=foo
echo 'something {{my_var}} bar' | sed -r "s/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/$\1/g"
```

I want to grab the name of the token (**my_var** in this case) and then substitute in the value of the environment variable with the same name.

Is this possible? Current the above prints `something $my_var bar` rather than `something foo bar` which is what I want.

I'm open to using another tool such awk instead if it's not possible with sed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you replace `{{my_var}}` with `$my_var`, you need to send the string for a second round of substitution explicitly.

with `eval`

```
$ eval echo "$(echo 'something {{my_var}} bar' | sed 's/{{\([^}]\+\)}}/$\1/g')"
something foo bar
```

or with a subshell

```
$ echo 'echo something {{my_var}} bar' | sed 's/{{\([^}]\+\)}}/$\1/g' | sh
something foo bar
```

Perl can do this 2nd round of evaluation on the replacement text only, not the whole output (with the `s///` function's `e` modifier):

```
$ echo 'something {{my_var}} bar' | perl -pe 's/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/$ENV{$1}/eg' 
something foo bar
```

Comment: Thanks, the Perl example is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: I also found [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html), it uses a slightly different token format in the input but has the required functionality

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use variable then add $ sign before variable.

export my_var=foo

> echo "something {{$my_var}} bar" | sed -r "s/{{(.*?)}}/$\1/g" | sed 's|[$]||g'

output:

> something foo bar

Comment: Getting closer, that gives me `something $foo bar` any ideas how to drop the $ in the resulting string? The format in the original string can be whatever makes it easiest

Comment: Thanks v much, that does work but i realise that there is an issue with my original example - $my_var is being substituted by the echo command rather than by sed so `echo 'something {{$my_var}} bar' | sed -r "s/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/$\1/g"` results in `something $$my_var bar` and `echo 'something {{$my_var}} bar' | sed -r "s/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/$\1/g" | sed 's|[$]||g'` results in `something my_var bar`

Comment: @toby: Please update your question with exactly what you are looking for.